# Why this Ruby query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create an object with this data. Problem is that as you see in code it isn't saving the data I'm giving nor the specified Id. Any ideas?

```
>> Attachment.create(:id => 50, :attachment_file_name => "tumblr_lbxifqK2LT1qa0qyy.jpg",  
:attachment_content_type  => "image/jpeg", :attachment_file_size=>80960, 
:attachment_updated_at => "2010-12-22 07:39:01", :created_at => "2010-12-22 07:39:02", 
:updated_at => "2011-03-07 02:14:05", :post_id => nil, :about_me => nil, :is_nsfw => nil, 
:attachable_id => nil, :attachable_type => nil, :is_default => nil, :temp_token => nil, 
:user_id => 1, :description => nil, :visits => nil)

=> #<Attachment id: 451, shortcut: "cjke", attachment_file_name: nil, 
attachment_content_type: nil, attachment_file_size: nil, attachment_updated_at: nil, 
created_at: "2011-03-07 04:46:15", updated_at: "2011-03-07 04:46:15", post_id: nil, 
about_me: nil, is_nsfw: nil, attachable_id: nil, attachable_type: nil, is_default: nil, 
temp_token: nil, user_id: 1, description: nil, visits: nil>
```

> > 

UPDATED: It's saving the username. Seems like what is not saving is the related paperclip info and the specified ID.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a protected attribute when dealing with ActiveRecord and Rails; you can't assign it a value manually.